# SQL: Get the most recent order from each customer

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display product from most recent orders on my main index page i have this code its working fine but i want to add order product thumb also in it which is stored in `ecs_goods` goods_thumb

```
    function index_get_recent_buy_query()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT ecs_users.user_name, ecs_order_goods.goods_id,
                 ecs_order_goods.goods_name, order_info.add_time, order_info.consignee
                FROM ecs_users, 
                (
                    SELECT order_id, user_id, add_time, consignee
                    FROM ecs_order_info
                    ORDER BY ecs_order_info.add_time DESC 
                    LIMIT 0 , 20
                ) AS order_info, 
                ecs_order_goods
                WHERE order_info.order_id = ecs_order_goods.order_id
                AND order_info.user_id = ecs_users.user_id;';

        $all = $GLOBALS['db']->getAll($sql);
```

> $arr[$idx]['goods_thumb']     = get_image_path($row['goods_id'],
>   $row['goods_thumb'], true);

I have the goods_id but i am confused on how can i include goods_thumb from `ecs_goods` in the above sql query

Comment: Are `ecs_goods` and `ecs_order_goods` the same? Looks like they are same.

Comment: ecs_goods and ecs_order_goods are different tables in database

Comment: Is `goods_id` present in both these tables? If not, which of the other tables contains this field? To include `goods_thumb` from `ecs_goods` table, you will need to find a common field between `ecs_goods` and some other table.

Comment: Yes goods_id is present in both "ecs_goods" "ecs_order_goods"  tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query part. I added a join with the `ecs_goods` table on the `goods_id` field and added `goods_thumb` field in the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT ecs_users.user_name, ecs_order_goods.goods_id,
ecs_order_goods.goods_name, order_info.add_time, order_info.consignee, ecs_goods.goods_thumb
FROM ecs_users, 
(
    SELECT order_id, user_id, add_time, consignee
    FROM ecs_order_info
    ORDER BY ecs_order_info.add_time DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 20
) AS order_info, 
ecs_order_goods, ecs_goods
WHERE order_info.order_id = ecs_order_goods.order_id
AND order_info.user_id = ecs_users.user_id
AND ecs_goods.goods_id = ecs_order_goods.goods_id;
```